# How to drop or delete a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, collections

What is the best way to drop a collection in MongoDB?

I am using the following:

```
db.collection.drop()
```

As described in [the manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/):

> **db.collection.drop()**
>
> Removes a collection from the database. The method also removes any
>   indexes associated with the dropped collection. The method provides a
>   wrapper around the drop command.

But how can I drop it from the command line?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

So either of these are valid ways to do it:

```
mongo <dbname> --eval 'db.<collection>.drop()'
#     ^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```
db.<collection>.drop()
#  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

For example, for a collection `mycollection` in a database `mydb` you would say:

```
mongo mydb --eval 'db.mycollection.drop()'
```

```
db.mycollection.drop()
```

---

This is the way I fully tested it, creating a database `mydb` with a collection `hello`.

- Create db `mydb`:

  ```
  > use mydb
  switched to db mydb
  ```
- Create a collection `mycollection`:

  ```
  > db.createCollection("mycollection")
  { "ok" : 1 }
  ```
- Show all the collections there:

  ```
  > db.getCollectionNames()
  [ "mycollection", "system.indexes" ]
  ```
- Insert some dummy data:

  ```
  > db.mycollection.insert({'a':'b'})
  WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
  ```
- Make sure it was inserted:

  ```
  > db.mycollection.find()
  { "_id" : ObjectId("55849b22317df91febf39fa9"), "a" : "b" }
  ```
- Delete the collection and make sure it is not present any more:

  ```
  > db.mycollection.drop()
  true
  > db.getCollectionNames()
  [ "system.indexes" ]
  ```

This also works (I am not repeating the previous commands, since it is just about recreating the database and the collection):

```
$ mongo mydb --eval 'db.mycollection.drop()'
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: mydb
true
$
```

Comment: On Windows 7 I had to use double quotes for this to work: `"db.hello.drop()"`

Answer (score 12):

To delete a collection `users` of database `mydb`:

```
> use mydb
> db.users.drop()
```

Answer (score 4):

We can also use,

```
> db["collection-name"].drop()
```

Its useful when you have some special characters in collection name like '-'

Answer (score 1):

```
--eval "db.getCollection('collection').drop()"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28801060)

Comment: This command line way in order to delete a collection has the advantage to be usable in scripts and avoid escaping behaviors. So its exactly an answer to: "What is the best way to drop a collection in MongoDB"

Comment: Hello. You answered a question that has an accepted back from 2015. You write a piece of command that will not run since it is not complete. And you offer no explanation why your answer works

Comment: In my previous comment i explained the obvious, maybe not for everyone, advantage of using the collection name as quoted parameter.

Comment: Well . First as you said it is you answered in a comment not in your original answer.Second when someone sees your answer the might run it as a single command inside a terminal not inside a mongo script

Comment: As the syntax, structure and parametric use is common knowledge there is no need to explain a simple code snippet which, as i mentioned several times, based in the context cant be misunderstood. Again i like the idea that someone with this special problem (p.e. dots in collection names) would identify a parameter as shell or mongo client command.