# Deletion Operation in AWS DocumentDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I have a question about deleting data in AWS DocumentDB.

I am using PuTTY to connect to EC2 instance and I use mongo shell command to connect with my Document DB.

I checked AWS DocumentDB documentation but I couldn't find how to delete singular data or whole data in one collection. For example I say:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> show databases
gg_events_document_db  0.000GB
rs0:PRIMARY> use gg_events_document_db
switched to db gg_events_document_db
rs0:PRIMARY> db.data_collection.find({"Type": "15"})
{"Type" : "15", "Humidity" : "14.3%"}
```

Now I have found the data and I want to delete it. What query should I need to run?

Or what if I want to delete all data in the collection? Without deleting my collection how can I do it?

Probably I am asking very basic questions but I couldn't find a query like this on my own.

I would be so happy if some experienced people in AWS DocumentDB can help me or share some resources.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon DocumentDB has compatibility with MongoDB APIs for 3.6 and 4.0. This said, the same APIs can be used for this need. With respect to:

> Or what if I want to delete all data in the collection? Without
> deleting my collection how can I do it?

Yo can use:

`db.data_collection.drop()`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thanks to you I found more resources:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948151/how-to-drop-or-delete-a-collection-in-mongodb
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/

Answer (score 1):

To delete a single document matching a filter, you would use the [deleteOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/#mongodb-method-db.collection.deleteOne) method.
For example, for your case that would be:

```
db.data_collection.deleteOne({"Type": "15"})
```

To delete all documents matching the filter, then use [deleteMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/#mongodb-method-db.collection.deleteMany).

There's also [remove()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) method, but it was deprecated.

The drop() method deletes the entire collection.